# Writing in file on web server using php

Tags: php, android

I have an android app that should upload photo to web server using php and POST connection, I receive the photo String correctly but my problem is with saving it in the server.

the php file I am connecting on it is in the below location:

```
www.mysite.com/project/code.php.
```

PHP is enabled on my website, and I enabled fopen command

I also tried to open any file and write anything in it but I fail (Echo doesn't executed and no file is saved). what is the problem? should I have special permissions to be able to create files?

Code:

```
?php
// Get image string posted from Android App
$base=$_REQUEST['image'];
// Get file name posted from Android App
$filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];
// Decode Image
$binary=base64_decode($base);
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
$file = fopen('uploadedimages/'.$filename, 'wb');
// Create File
fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);
echo 'Image upload complete, Please check your php file directory';
?>
```

Comment: Check your error logs Sheriff, you'll find them to chick full of information.

Comment: you are missing the starting `<`. The `header() ` line is unnecessary and the wrong content type.

Comment: you're telling the browser you're sending a bitmap image (the header() call has **NO** effect on what you're fwriting), then output some text, which is invalid bmp data. if you want to output a success message, your content-type header should be text/html or text/plain. and you're simply assuming the fopen/fwrite succeeded. they return boolean false on failure,w hich you're outright ignoring.

Comment: Try with var_dump($_FILES) and var_dump($_POST); to see what are you getting from android app.

Comment: @Gerald, this is typo error, I removed the header() and the problem still exist. the fopen command isn't working at all

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, Yes I received the inputs and I can echo it, the problem only in fopen .. it is not working at all, and I checked the server php settings and the fopen is enabled. I can't find the problem till now

Answer (score 0):

Check your Apache (or equivalent) logs to see if it is a permissions issue. If it is, you can set the owner of the folder to Apache from the linux command line with `sudo chown www-data:www-data /uploadedimages/` and give owner-write permissions with `chmod 0744 /uploadedimages/`. That command also gives global and group read permissions, so you should double check if that is suitable.

Comment: it seems it is something in the server, I made the file with a simple fopen command and it is not working, I also checked the logs but nothing thrown to it regarding this access.